# Set Up apache MySQL and PHP (development environment) on Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: macos, php, mysql, web-development, setup

How to tutorial or link to one please.

EDIT:

MAMP is a large download. Also, something a little more manual would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (Macintosh, Apache, Mysql and PHP) is probably the easiest way to get up and running.

> With just a few mouse-clicks, you can
>   install Apache, PHP and MySQL for Mac
>   OS X!
>
> MAMP installs a local server
>   environment in a matter of seconds on
>   your Mac OS X computer, be it
>   PowerBook or iMac. Like similar
>   packages from the Windows- and
>   Linux-world, MAMP comes free of
>   charge.
>
> MAMP is installed in the typical Mac
>   fashion: very easily. MAMP will not
>   compromise any existing Apache
>   installation already running with your
>   OS X. You can install Apache, PHP and
>   MySQL without starting a script or
>   having to change any configuration
>   files!
>
> Furthermore, if MAMP is no longer
>   needed, it is sufficient to delete the
>   MAMP folder and everything returns to
>   its original status (i.e. MAMP does
>   not modify any of the "normal" OS X).

[Here](http://michaeldoig.net/33/mamp-video-tutorial-now-available.htm) is a MAMP video tutorial which goes through the setup and configuration of MAMP.

Comment: Is there a manual way to do this?

Comment: There sure is, here's a great tutorial: http://www.klauskomenda.com/archives/2008/10/07/installing-apache-mysql-and-php-on-leopard/

Comment: +1, also for the comment with the alternative. I had been using XAMPP, which got kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) for either windows or mac.  Its packaged nicely and runs in its own directories.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for Mac because of its Control Panel.